# How to search a collapsed file item in NERDTree vim plugin?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

`NERDTree` is my best vim plugin. To find a file or directory item, I move to my cursor to tree view, and use `/`. But I still don't know how to find a file item which be in collapsed(closed) tree. `NERDTree` does not support this? How do you do find a file?

Answer (score 9):

The filename is not present in NERDTree's buffer so `/pattern` won't work. You'll have to use other tools to reach your goal.

If the file is in a directory that is part of Vim's `path` you can use `:find` like that:

```
:find filename
:find fil<Tab>
:find pattern
```

See `:help path` for how to add directories.

You can also do `:e /path/to/directory<Tab>`.

Using `**` you can force Vim to look into subdirectories as well:

```
:e /path/**/user<Tab>
```

will allow you to choose from a list of all files starting with `user`. That's pretty neat.

If Vim's working directory is the directory of the current buffer (that's not automatic, see `:help autochdir`), something like

```
:e ../../**/*.json
```

would bring a list of all JSON files in your project. Well, I don't know how your project is laid out but you get the picture.

See `:help file-searching` for a detailed explanation.

---

Alternatively, you could use a plugin. [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) is a nice and powerful "fuzzy" file-naviation plugin that does one thing that I find super useful: when invoked, it looks up and up until it finds a VCS "marker" (a .git directory, for example) and uses it a starting point for your search. This makes opening files in the current project almost "fun".

Answer (score 0):

You can use GPicker as CtrlP or CommandT alternative (Textmate feature clone) - it is written in C and is very fast, it integrates well with VIM or emacs. Instalation instructions on my blog post.

http://blog.wysocki.org.pl/2012/06/vim-gpicker-sublimetext-2-like-files.html